# What is the equivalent of Octopus package library in Azure Devops

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Our current CI pipleline uses Team City and Octopus deploy but I'm evaluating changing this to Azure Devops doing both the build and deployment.

The solution we have consists of some ASP.NET code stored in GitHub which is compiled by Team City and then that along with some other packages which don't change are all deployed to a server. The directory they deploy to is wiped so that it is a fresh install each time.

So far I've managed to create the build pipleline and am then using the IIS deployment process to deploy the build (haven't got it to wipe the existing site yet).

What do I use for the other parts of the solution which are static though? In Octopus these are stored in the package library and have been manually uploaded. Should I be looking at Azure artifacts for this?

Also how should I go about deploying these? Should I create multiple web app deploy steps, do something different or is there a way to select multiple packages on the one web app deploy step?

Comment: Are the following answers helpful to you ?

Comment: Sounds liek the right thing. Just need to get back onto the project to try them :)

Comment: After trying, if it works, you can accept one solution as an answer,this will help users who get the same issues more easily to find the solution and we could archive this thread.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of the package library was Azure Artifacts. I has the functionality to be set up as a NuGet feed however I had issues publishing into it. Potentially due to two factor authentication.

My eventual solution was to set up repos containing the static files each with a pipeline that just copied files and published an artifact at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Octopus packing and deployment steps in your Azure DevOps pipeline by installing the extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octopusdeploy.octopus-deploy-build-release-tasks).

What you can do with your static content is to include it in your code repo in a way that gets compiled and packed by Octopus and the deployed as a whole. However, if moving the static content from Octopus to your code is not allowed, then you could try handling the merging of the compiled solution plus static content via adding different process steps in Octopus.

Answer (score 1):

As the Package library in Octopus deploy (last time is used it) is setup as a Nuget feed, it's a pretty fair comparison. Azure Artifacts allows you to upload several package types including Nuget, so you should be able to use that the way you did the package library.

As for the cleanup of you site, it depends a bit on the task you use during the release.

If you are using the 'IIS web app deploy' step, checking the 'Remove Additional Files at Destination' box would fit your needs.
As you refer to your target environment as 'a machine' i'm not sure what kind of infra you are you using but in case of some IaaS setup powershell remoting[1] might also be a way to go.

[1] https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/